# Mobile App Unique ID detection in PHP

Tags: php, android, ios, mobile

I'm building a mobile app which will call a search engine on my website.  I have PHP code to detect if a person is coming in through a Mobile device.  However, I want to see if I can detect if they are coming in through my app versus a regular page browse.

In the past, I've had a hidden field on a form submission, but this is not feasible anymore.

I want to know if there is a way if somebody accesses a page on my website through the mobile app or a mobile browser?

One option is to pass a PHP $_GET parameter, but I'm looking for other solutions.

Comment: What would be the point? Are you looking for a security fix for example? Even if that is the case all it would take is a packet sniffer to work out what's being sent and it can then be faked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps override the user agent used in the mobile app, or send an additional header that your PHP scripts can look for

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the default user agent to identify your application.